# How to delete session variable after use in Django templates

Tags: python, django, templates, session

```
def demo(request):
    if data:
        request.session['success'] = "Success'
    else:
        request.session['failed'] = "Failed'
```

Here I've defined one method and in that if I got data then success session is stored or else failed one.

After that I'm **redirecting** user to the another page and there I'm displaying this session variable in template.

But after the display of this session status I want to delete that session variable. Because I want to **display this message only onetime** to user. If user refreshes the page then this variable **should be deleted**.

I tried to find online but didn't get any help. So please help me with this.

Thank you

P.S: I'm redirecting user to another page using `return redirect('page')`. Rendering another template using `return render(request, "my_tmp.html")` doesn't work because that will only load template in current url (URL will not change, only content will). So I don't want that. I know I can use this way by passing session variable in context but that's not I want.

I'm using Django 2

Comment: Then you should not use session variables I think, but messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do *not* use session variables for that. Session variables should be used, like the name suggests, for variables that typically have a livespan that is the same as the session. Doing this yourself will also result in a lot of coding, special edge-cases, and likely it will be error-prone.

Django has tooling to show messages to the user: the [*messages framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/). The documentation specifies how you can set up this framework, although by default it is already installed (so if you did not remove it, there is not much that you need to do).

In your view, you can then add messages, like:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def demo(request):
    if data:
        messages.success(request, 'Operation successful')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Operation failed!')
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {})
```

In your template you can then render the messages like specified in the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages):

> ```
> {% if messages %}
> <ul class="messages">
>     {% for message in messages %}
>     <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
>     {% endfor %}
> </ul>
> {% endif %}
> ```

You can for example include that in your `base.html` (and thus extend all other pages from that super template) such that you render the messages on all pages.

Django will automatically clear the messages once these are rendered. So there is no need to do the bookkeeping yourself.

Comment: Thanks bro it's working! Thank you for showing me right path. I'm beginner in Django. I'm used to use session for messages but now I know the right tool for that. And your explanation is awesome. Thank you once again.